# How to start Titanium application ported to Android without welcome Appcelerator screen?

Tags: android, titanium

I am new to Titanium and created a HelloWorld application. Every time my application starts up a Titanium startscreen is show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done relatively simple. In your titanium project inside the resources folder is a folder for resources which are special for android. Titanium will look into this folder and use the Default.png as the image to display while starting up. Just replace the file that is already existing in this folder with your splash screen image. Be sure to get use Default.png and not default.png because on the device titanium will be case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the thing is that I don't want to have welcome screen.

Comment: What would you like it to do while the application is loading? Have a blank screen?

Comment: You could create a splash image that contains a "screenshot" of those buttons and tabs. I believe that's how the other iPhone apps do it. The Contacts app does this I think. It makes you think/feel that the UI controls are already loaded when you open it but in reality you're just seeing a splash image.

Comment: You can not display the UI imidently as it would be possible with "native Java" because the Titanium runtime needs to be initalized befor displaying any UI. That's wy you are forced to have a spash screen where other Android Apps works perfectly without one.

Answer (score -1):

Go to tiapp.xml , remove the splash screen nodes, 
the  Splash  screen will not  show  again.